# Making react-router link look like my default link

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styled-components

I use `styled-components` to style my default links as follows:

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import {
  fontSize
} from 'styled-system';

const Link = a `
  ${fontSize};
  color: white;

  &:link {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
`;

export default Link;
```

I would like to use the exact same style for `react-router`s Link component. Should I be using `css` from `styled-components` or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

One way is not using React router link component and instead using your own link component with an onclick property of props.history.push("ROUTE")

Answer (score 0):

You can style any react-component (like the react-router Link) by using parantheses:

```js
const StyledLink = styled(Link)`
    color: red;
`;
```

See the documentation for more reference:
https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-components